# Horizontal scrolling w/ parallax effect pure CSS

Tags: css, scroll, parallax

First of all, I'm a total beginner and I'm trying to do things way above my league I think.

So here's my problem: I'm actually making a horizontal scrolling website using pure CSS with some parallax into it.
While I've managed to make some things work. The parallax effect is getting me crazy.

On the second slide of my template, I'm not able to make my background stick to the top inside my div, it scrolls down for w/e the reason. Also, I've made a text on top of it with a background-clip, while it works on Chrome, it doesn't on Firefox...

If you guys got a solution, I'm up for it.

Here's the website: http://triztwtv.free.fr/portfolio/

Also, I'm doing this in pure CSS but if you got a good JS framework to make my dreams come true, I'm up for it as well.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/?more_on=xron.net). See How to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It also very helpful to show in your Question an expected result, and quote any (exact) errors you are getting. You are expected to show any research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if its exactly what you wanted to do but I tried fixing it.

First I removed these lines:

```
background-attachment:fixed;
background-position-x:100vh;
```

from your code and updated this part of your CSS like this:

```
  .two {
    order: 2;
    margin-top: 30vh;

  }
  .bkg1{
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/D54n4T5/1.png"); 
}
```

Centre the text in the window the same as you did in .one, for the first screen, by setting the margin-top, so it doesn't stick to the top. I tested in in Firefox, and it looks like it works as you wanted.

Comment: The thing is it makes the parallax effect disappear. 
I'm actually trying to solve the issue using React for the horizontal scroll. Using position: absolute; makes the trick but it also makes the page unscrollable (have to mouse click and move to see the results)

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Sorry about that! I had another look but it seems difficult to use pure CSS for something like that. If you can't do it using React, maybe try looking into using GSAP with ScrollTrigger. You might be able to achieve the look that you want that way.